# stop DIVs moving eachother

Tags: html, css, format, alignment, margin

I have 2 divs that I want to position close together, however they keep moving eachother. They are both under the main div.

HTML:

```html
<div id="header">
  <div id="title">Social</div>
</div>
<div id="main">
  <div id='notif'><strong>Incorrect details.</strong>
  </div>
  <div id="signin">
    <form name="signinform" action="authenticate.php" method="post" onsubmit="return validate(this)" id="signinform">
      <p>
        <input placeholder="Username / Email" class="input" type="text" name="user" id="user" maxlength="50">
      </p>
      <p>
        <input placeholder="Password" class="input" type="password" name="password" id="password" maxlength="50">
      </p>
      <p>
        <input type="checkbox" name="remember" id="remember" value="checked">
        <label for="remember">Remember me</label>
      </p>
      <p>
        <input class="button" type="submit" value="Sign in">
      </p>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

The CSS is as follows:

Main body which both divs comes under:

```
#main {
    padding-top: 50px;
}
```

Form div:

```
#signin {
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    width: 400px;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 150px;
}
```

Error div:

```
#notif {
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    width: 400px;
    height: 20px;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 140px;
}
```

I know that perhaps it has something to do with the `position` attribute..

Here is an image of what it looks like now, as you can see, I want both of the center objects to be close together without pushing each other away from the vertical center.

[image]

Comment: take off the `margin-top` from `#notif`? If not, please provide a working demo that reproduces the issue

Comment: Post your HTML as well please.  A complete code example is always useful.

Comment: All that does is move the notif div to the top but the gap between notif and signin div is still there...

Comment: @Thug_Life_Imti: Then take it off the `#signin` div. But again, we're stabbing in the dark without any markup to see what these id's are referring to

Comment: @j08691 added html..

Answer (score 0):

remove the margin-top from the `#signin` div - as this is what is putting pixels between the `#notif` div and the `#signin` div.

```css
#main {
  padding-top: 50px;
}
#signin {
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  width: 400px;
  margin: auto;
}
#notif {
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  width: 400px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 140px;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <div id="title">Social</div>
</div>
<div id="main">
  <div id='notif'><strong>Incorrect details.</strong>
  </div>
  <div id="signin">
    <form name="signinform" action="authenticate.php" method="post" onsubmit="return validate(this)" id="signinform">
      <p>
        <input placeholder="Username / Email" class="input" type="text" name="user" id="user" maxlength="50">
      </p>
      <p>
        <input placeholder="Password" class="input" type="password" name="password" id="password" maxlength="50">
      </p>
      <p>
        <input type="checkbox" name="remember" id="remember" value="checked">
        <label for="remember">Remember me</label>
      </p>
      <p>
        <input class="button" type="submit" value="Sign in">
      </p>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

## Debugging

In this sort of situation, your page inspector is going to be your best friend.

In chrome, for example, when the page inspector is open, hovering an element will show you the margins of the element, as well as any padding being given to it.

Comment: Yes but now the problem is that when the error div isn't there, the form div moves right up to the top

Comment: I want the signin form div's margin to be relative from the top header, how do I do this?